# Unable to see the source tree through Finder while doing repo sync in OSX

Tags: android, macos, osx-lion, android-source

I am downloading the android source as per the instructions mentioned in source.android.com. I have made a different case sensitive file system and have made a directory in it and doing a repo sync. I can see through terminal `ls -la`

the following files

```
Aruns-MacBook-Pro:ANDROID_DIR ArunAbraham$ ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 ArunAbraham  staff  102 May 14 17:26 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 ArunAbraham  staff  340 May 14 17:23 ..
drwxr-xr-x  6 ArunAbraham  staff  238 May 14 17:27 .repo
```

But i can't see the same through the Finder. Is this how it is supposed to behave ?

Could someone explain me this behavior ? Or have i done something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finder treats files starting with a `.` as hidden files.  `ls` does as well but the `-a` option you gave overrides it.

Here's a tip to [show all hidden files in the Finder](http://www.mikesel.info/show-hidden-files-mac-os-x-10-7-lion/), but you will see everything, not just theones you want.  Short version:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```